# Why does my sorting function produce such an unusual output?

Tags: java, class, sorting, comparator, comparable

I have a program that reads from a csv file full of peoples last names, first names, and birth years, assigns them into a special class array, and then gets sorted according to their last name. I believe that my code is working, so all I have to do to verify this is output the list and see if indeed all of the people were sorted by their last name. However, I am having trouble finding the right syntax to do this.
Here is the code of my Main.java, where I think the issue must be.

```
package project_1_sorting;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Main 

{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // open file input stream
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Data 18k.csv")); // double check where this is trying to read it from

        // read file line by line
        String line = null;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        int index = 0;
        Human[] pplArray = new Human[18000];
                int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Human ppl = new Human();
            scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String data = scanner.next();
                if (index == 0)
                    ppl.setLastName(data);
                else if (index == 1)
                    ppl.setFirstName(data);
                else if (index == 2)
                    ppl.setBirthYear(data);
                else
                    System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
                index++;
            }
                        ppl.setKey(0); //change this for later things, you can use loop
                        ppl.setOrder(0); //change this to 1 if you want to invert the list of people
            index = 0;
            pplArray[i] = ppl;
                        i++;
                        System.out.println(pplArray);
        }
        //close reader
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(pplArray); // create


           Selection_Sort selection = new Selection_Sort();   


            for (int j = 0; j < 18000; j++)
     {
         System.out.println(pplArray[j]);
     }
    }

}
```

So I was expecting this to output a giant list of all of my people from the csv file(ordered), with all of their info in the same format as they originally were, right. (one person per row, with 3 collumns for their 3 strings). However this is what I got instead:

```
run:
Test
17
true
0.142857
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The one thing that I have noticed is that one of the last lines that reads

```
Selection_Sort selection = new Selection_Sort();
```

It says that "Variable selection is not used."
I think that it is saying that I am not properly using my selection sort. I am creating an object of that class, but not using it.

here is my Selection_Sort.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package project_1_sorting;

public class Selection_Sort 
{
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
    { // Sort a[] into increasing order.
        int N = a.length; // array length
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        { // Exchange a[i] with smallest entry in a[i+1...N).
            int min = i; // index of minimal entr.
            for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
                if (less(a[j], a[min])) min = j;
            exch(a, i, min);
        }
    }
// See page 245 for less(), exch(), isSorted(), and main()

private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w)
    { 
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0; 
    }
private static void exch(Comparable[] a, int i, int j)
    { 
    Comparable t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t; 
    }

}
```

I think that, in order to actually sort my data from the csv file in the right order. I have to do something to the affect of

```
 Selection_Sort selection = new Selection_Sort();   
 selection.sort(pplArray[]);
```

However, the second line of code creates an error message:

```
'.class' expected
 cannot find symbol
 symbol: class pplArray
 location : class main
```

If I remove the brackets on pplArray:

```
 Selection_Sort selection = new Selection_Sort();   
 selection.sort(pplArray);
```

The error message changes to

```
incompatible types: Human[] cannot be converted to Comparable
```

This makes me wonder if there is something at fault with my Human class, so here is my Human.java:

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package project_1_sorting;



class Human{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String birthYear;
    int Key;
    int Order;
    public Human() // A constructor
    { 
    }

public int compareTo(Human person)
{
    if (Order == 0)
    {
      if (Key == 0)       
            return lastName.compareTo(person.lastName );
     else if  (Key == 1)    
            return firstName.compareTo(person.firstName );
     else 
            return birthYear.compareTo(person.birthYear );
    }
    else
            {
    if (Key == 0)       
            return (lastName.compareTo(person.lastName ) ) * -1;
    else if  (Key == 1)    
            return ( firstName.compareTo(person.firstName ) ) * -1;
    else 
            return ( birthYear.compareTo(person.birthYear ) ) * -1;
    }
}

public void printHuman ()
{
    StdOut.print(lastName + " " + firstName + " " + birthYear);
}

public void setKey (int k)
{
    Key = k;
}

public void setOrder (int o)
{
    Order = o;
}

public void setFirstName(String fName)
{
     firstName = fName;
}

public void setLastName(String lName)
{
     lastName = lName;
}

public void setBirthYear(String bYear)
{
     birthYear = bYear;
}

 }
```

In case it is relevant, int key is supposed to allow me to pick by what variable I want to sort (first name, last name , or birth year), and int order is supposed to allow me to reverse the order in which people are ordered (least to greatest, greatest to least).

If I can't use comparable, does that mean I have to use a comparator? If so, could someone show me how to do this?

If anyone knows what this is all about, please let me know. If there is nothing else wrong with this Main.java, I can post my other .java files.

One thing I did notice was that, even when I commented out my selection sort function call, and all of the printline commands in this .java file, the same output was displayed on my screen.

Please let me know what you think, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. However, how will the compiler know that your `Human` class is `Comparable`? You must not only provide the method `compareTo()`, but also put `implements Comparable` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Human` class seems ok - but though you've implemented the `compareTo()` function, you haven't stated your class implements the `Comparable` interface (which is the compilation error you're getting):

```
class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
```

You'll probably then need to annotate the `compareTo()` function:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Human person)
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes that you suggested. However, I am still getting the same unusual output. I also added a line in Main.Java at the end            Selection_Sort selection = new   Selection_Sort();   
           selection.sort(pplArray);

Comment: Since `sort()` is a static function, you don't need to create an instance of `Selection_Sort`. So just running `Selection_Sort.sort(pplArray);` should suffice. Other than that, what "unusual output" are you seeing? Are you talking about output from building your project, or from running it?